# Какой вариант предпочтительнее: "большая честь" - "было бы большой честью"?

Tags: выбор-варианта, стилистическая-сочетаемость

*Для меня было бы большой честью познакомиться с вами.*

Или

*Для меня большая честь познакомиться с вами.*

Чем обоснован выбор?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Для меня было бы большой честью познакомиться **с вами**. (2) Для меня большая честь познакомиться **с вами**.

Если речь идет **о втором лице**, то верно только предложение (2), так как эту фразу можно сказать человеку при знакомстве с ним.

Другое дело, если речь идет **о третьем лице.**

(1) Для меня было бы большой честью познакомиться **с ним.** (2) Для меня большая честь познакомиться **с ним**.

Здесь речь идет о  знакомстве в будущем. В первом предложении высказано **вежливое предположение о возможности** познакомиться. Во втором предложении вопрос о будущем знакомстве **уже решен** положительно.